# Unpacking iterable using map

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, iterable-unpacking

Assuming I have two iterables of numbers of the same length

```
weights = range(0, 10)
values = range(0, 100, 10)
```

I need to count weighted sum. I know that it can be done with list comprehension

```
weighted_sum = sum(weight * value for weight, value in zip(weights, values))
```

I wonder if it can be done using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) like

```
import operator

weighted_sum = sum(map(operator.mul, zip(weights, values)))
```

but this gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: op_mul expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

so my question: is there any way of passing unpacked tuples to function using `map`?

Comment: shouldn't it be `weighted_sum = sum(map(operator.mul, weights, values))` without the `zip`? Or, as hinted at in `map`'s documentation, maybe [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) helps

Comment: Done, though as [Rahul suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039847/321973), using `numpy` is even better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` doesn't need the `zip`, just use

```
weighted_sum = sum(map(operator.mul, weights, values))
```

From [`map`'s Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

> If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.

Also mentioned in `map`'s documentation is that instead you can use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of `map` for already `zip`ped input.

---

As [Rahul hinted at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039847/321973), using `numpy` is always a good idea when dealing with numerics, actually something like

```
import numpy as np

np.asarray(weights) * values
```

already should do the trick (though in contrast to `map` this *requires* the two arrays to be of same length, while `map` would map the shortest length).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
>>> import operator
>>>
>>> weights = range(0, 10)
>>> values = range(0, 100, 10)
>>> sum(map(lambda i:operator.mul(*i), zip(weights, values)))
2850
```

Or

```
>>> sum(map(operator.mul, weights, values))
2850
```

Comment: I suggest to use the second attempt.

Comment: First one seems rather convoluted, the second one looks more Pythonic to me (maybe that's because I was just thinking the same ;)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Yeah, actually, there' no need to use `zip`. The second way is much better and Pythonic. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also attempt with `numpy`,

```
In [45]: import numpy as np

In [46]: sum(map(np.multiply,weights,values))
Out[46]: 2850
```

As per Tobias Kienzler's Suggestion,

```
In [52]: np.sum(np.array(weights) * values)
Out[52]: 2850
```

Comment: Good point, especially for larger arrays this might speed things up. Though, then you might as well convert the arrays into numpy ones and simply use `*` for the scalar product, which already sums the element-wise product anyway.

Comment: thanks, but i need it for tests in project without `numpy`, so it would be an overkill :-)